# Brightness for a SVG path not working in Chrome but in Firefox

Tags: css, class, google-chrome, firefox, svg

I have created an [**interactive map**](http://arda-maps.org/ages/first/) that shows when for instance a river is mousehovered and so on. So this is how it shall look like. In Firefox that works but not in Chrome:

[image]

So how can I enable the brigthness successful in Chrome as well. Here the class I use:

```
.highlightElement {
    fill: #666;
    filter: brightness(125%);
    -webkit-filter: brightness(125%);
    -moz-filter: brightness(125%);
    -o-filter: brightness(125%);
    -ms-filter: brightness(125%);
}
```

Btw the *fill* is for the lakes I have on the map. They are also not working in Chrome. But somehow changing the **text color** when hovering on them is **working** in Chrome (but this I'm realizing with *fill*).

So this is something with the brigthness property I believe.

Comment: Report Chrome bugs here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: Yeah but I'm not sure if this is actually a bug. Let's see, thanks: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=494947&thanks=494947&ts=1433152536

Comment: please share a minimal test case on codepen or jsfiddle

Comment: Well the linked website is too much you mean? I mean as you can see it works in Firefox, so the technology is there. There is just something with the properties in Chrome that leads to the issue. So what would the small example differ from the actual project? Just tell me I mean I have no problem doing a small example =) But I don't see the advantage from this.

Comment: I have a different experience: in Firefox (68.0.1 on OSX 10.13), CSS filter brightness only affects SVG fill areas, but not SVG stroke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the Chromium project is really slow on those issues. It is still not fixed and it seems that it has a really low priority: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=494947&thanks=494947&ts=1433152536